# Iterating over JS Object not getting all attributes

Tags: javascript, css, dom

When trying to iterate over document.styleSheets it doesn't go over every attribute.

This results when console logging document.styleSheets

```
StyleSheetList {0: CSSStyleSheet, 1: CSSStyleSheet, length: 2, item: function}
    0: CSSStyleSheet
    1: CSSStyleSheet
    2: CSSStyleSheet
    length: 3
```

And iterating over these attributes gives me

```
0 elementLoader.js:11
1 elementLoader.js:11
length elementLoader.js:11
```

It seems like the last stylesheet is not enumerable but I have no idea why and it happens to be the one I wish to look at.

Any ideas?

The code I'm running:

```
var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
console.log(styleSheets);
for (var i in styleSheets)
{
    console.log(i);
}
```

In this example printing document.styleSheets[2] returns null.

**SOLUTION:**
Turn's out that angular was pulling some trickery. By loading the code within a directive instead of a script tag I was able to iterate all of the style sheets. What a weird error.

Comment: Where is the `2` line coming from? It's not in the first line of the console.log.

Comment: Can you show what you're doing to get each output?

Comment: Put up the code i'm running

Comment: Suggestion - `StyleSheetList` is an arraylike object (has `length` and integers as indexes), use array type iteration instead of object enumeration.

Comment: Have tried both, object enumeration was simply to visualize the object better.

Comment: Do you have a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: The first line of `console.log` only shows 2 stylesheets, just like your enumeration. I guess the rest of that is when you click the disclosure triangle, right? When I do that here, I see the same 2 stylesheets as in the first line. My guess is something is dynamically modifying the stylesheets, and you disclosed it while there was a third sheet.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird. I was thinking that the object had a "Dont Enum" on it. I tested printing the entire list before and after the iteration and it does not change. For some reason the 2 index is just not alterable or delectable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn's out that angular was pulling some trickery. By loading the code within a directive instead of a script tag I was able to iterate all

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do this instead:

```
var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
console.log(styleSheets);
for (var i in styleSheets)
{
    console.log(styleSheets[i]); // Log stylesheet instead of index
}
```

Comment: I was logging the index merely to show what was being returned. If i show the actualy stylesheet i get the first two from the list only.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down what you have shown to us so far.

**Part1.**

```
StyleSheetList {0: CSSStyleSheet, 1: CSSStyleSheet, length: 2, item: function}
```

The above appears to be what you are seeing in your console.log, you are then expanding this object to see the content and then you see (as @Barmar suggested).

```
    0: CSSStyleSheet
    1: CSSStyleSheet
    2: CSSStyleSheet
    length: 3
```

This suggests that you have loaded a stylesheet after the original logging.

**Part 2**

You use enumeration rather than iteration on the `StyleSheetList` and you posted a copy-paste

```
0 elementLoader.js:11
1 elementLoader.js:11
length elementLoader.js:11
```

Which needs to be cleaned up as the `elementLoader.js:11` is part of the copy-paste and not the actual log, and you have.

```
0
1
length
```

Which matches what was first logged before a later stylesheet was loaded.

Note that you see the `length` property name as it is ennumerable, you wouldn't see this is you use iteration.

Comment: As stated earlier, I just wanted to show what attributes of the object were given during enumeration. Also the styleSheeList itself is not changed as I can print it with the same contents before and after enumeration. I just tried to put this up to JSFiddle to see if the same error existed and it didn't. Perhaps it's because i'm using anuglar?

Comment: Without more information or a demonstration it is impossible to take this any further.